# Modify Nth Digit

Tags: c, math

Given a number, I want to modify the Nth digit of the number.

For example, given 1237645, I want to change the 4<sup>th</sup> digit from the right, which is 7 in this case, to say 5.

The only way in which I can think of is to do this

```
N = 1237645
fourthDigit = (N / 1000) % 10    
N -= fourthDigit * 1000       // make fourth digit 0
N += 5 * 1000                 // make fourth digit 5
```

But this is quite inefficient. Is there a better way to this? I cannot use array to represent N due to memory constraints.

Comment: Sorry modified. It was %10

Comment: That's likely to be as well as you can do with conventional binary representation of numbers. If you use binary-coded decimal (BCD), this could be done very quickly with bitwise boolean operations, but then all arithmetic would require extra instructions. BCD stores one decimal digit in 4 bits, so a 32-bit int can represent +- 9,999,999 or unsigned up to 99,999,999. Interestingly, the ancient 8086 had special instructions to support BCD that were supported for a long time, but have been deprecated and abandoned in recent x86 versions.

Comment: Looks interesting. In fact this would be just as memory efficient in my case because I have 4 digit numbers represented by arrays of shorts (so a few bits are left free). I need to learn how to efficiently implement it though because at the moment I can only think of bitfields.

Comment: What real world problem would require an efficient solution for this? Just curious.

Comment: I working on storing states of Rubik's Cubes. But interfacing this would be really really useful in general. This would be in a way generalization of binary arithmetic to higher bases (plus efficient storage and access).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one arithmetic operation:

```
N = 1237645
fourthDigit = (N / 1000) % 10    
N -= (fourthDigit-5) * 1000
```

provided `fourthDigit` >= 5, otherwise the last line becomes

```
N += (newDigit-fourthDigit)*1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this embedded system programming?
If it is, then try storing numbers as binary-coded decimal (BCD), then convert to binary if you need to. It is probably easier to convert from BCD to binary than the other way around.
Also see: http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/bcd.html

BTW, right here in the room with me is a clock which keeps time in BCD. This way, it doesn't have to divide by 10 for display.